# 3D моделирование фигуры в C/C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, c, opengl, c++, 3d

Всем привет.

Скиньте пожалуйста ссылок или литературы по 3D моделирования на С или С++.

Может кто  знает статьи по этой теме, где все описывается подробно?

Можно ли смоделировать 3D фигуру без OpenGL? (опять как, как это сделать, можете скинуть ссылки на инфу?)

Пример работы [вот](http://www.kursovik.com/programming/320352.html).

Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Все можно. Вы только определитесь с конкретной задачей, а то "3D моделирование на С++" звучит достаточно размыто. 

ЗЫ. На OpenGL вас хорошо натаскают [уроки от NeHе](http://nehe.gamedev.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я думаю что ссылки на складе хранят не многие. Вопрос действительно не ясен. 
Хотя если ответить на то что я понял и без OGL, то надо гуглить на SDK, DirectX и их родные файлы моделей .x

Ну вот как-то так.